# AWS Elasticache - increase memcached item size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, memcached, amazon-elasticache, flask-cache

Im using the `memcached` module on `AWS Elasticache` in my python Flask app (with `Flask-Cache`)

When i try to set a file that is less than `1MB` i need to repeatedly access to the cache, i have no issues. But when the file size increases more than a MB (the file could be a text file/csv/xlsx etc), i get the following error

> Error: error 37 from memcached_set: SUCCESS

Im guessing its because of the size limit on a memcached item which is capped at 1MB. How do i increase this item limit to say 5-6 MB in AWS Elasticache ?

Are there any issues in increasing this item size limit in memcached ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This page lists the parameters that we can tinker with in memcached
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheParameterGroups.Memcached.html

> If you do not specify a parameter group for your Memcached cluster, then a default parameter group (default.memcached1.4) will be used. You cannot change the values of any parameters in the default parameter group; however, you can always create a custom parameter group and assign it to your cluster at any time.

Create a new Cache Parameter group either from the AWS Console or using the AWS CLI and set the max_item_size to the size that fits your needs. Reboot your cache cluster for this change to kickin.

[image]

On your local testing machine, if you have memcache installed, then you can increase the object size by adding this line at `/etc/memcached.conf`

```
# Increase object size limit
-I 128M
```

Then reboot your memcache with `sudo service memcached restart` for the changes to settle in

Comment: If there are any potential sideeffects/issues with increasing the memcached item size limit to an arbitrary large number, do let me know ? Thanks